# Can't figure out why Goutte not working for this

Tags: goutte

OK I'm trying to get a title from my blog using Goutte:

The below code works (titles returned) for $url= https://twoggle.com, or https://ninjaforms.com/blog but NOT for https://twoggle.com/blog/  (I've looked at the source and nothing I can see should be causing errors?)

```
$goutteClient = new \Goutte\Client();
        $crawler = $goutteClient->request('GET', $url);

        $titles = $crawler->filter('html > head > title');
        $titles = $titles->each(function ($node, $i) {
            echo $node->text();
            return $node->text();
        });
```

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: Does not get the title because the response you are filtering does not have one. You should check the final url and see if any redirect/reload occur. You need to `var_dump` the response and see if this is the expected page.

Comment: turns out was some unclosed meta tags (not closed with '/>' but rather just '>'). thanks

Comment: I actually believe this to be a bug / limitation of Goutte/DomCrawler: 
If i have <meta ...> <other tags> then <meta 2> tags, Goutte crawler does not recognize the <meta 2..> tags !